# multithreaded rpc on linux(SUN rpc)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, rpc, sun

I am trying to implement multithreaded rpc server on linux, seems that it works fine for udp, however when I use tcp, I get the below error:

```
if (!svc_getargs (transp, (xdrproc_t) _xdr_argument, (caddr_t) &argument)) {  
    svcerr_decode (transp);
    return;
}
```

## ./ClientSQUARE 127.0.0.1 12

127.0.0.1: RPC: Server can't decode arguments

P.S. I am going by the below example:

http://lxer.com/module/newswire/view/14311/index.html

Has anyone seen such an issue ?